# Remote running spark job

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera, apache-spark

Trying to run start  Spark job.

Spark installed as parcel inside Cloudera Hadoop.

How to start Spark job remotely with Java API?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "Start Spark Job Remotely"? Will not it be enough get connected via SSH to your Spark Cluster and call spark-submit script? You can do the same steps programmatically!!

Comment: I have some web service at host "A" and CDH cluster at another hosts. I want run job via some API from server "A" without spark-submit command. It is possible?

Comment: Looks like you need https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver

Answer (score 1):

To submit Spark applications programmatically from code as opposed to using the submit scripts, you will need to create a `SparkContext`.

Here is the Java API [SparkContext](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html)

To configure the context further you provide it a `SparkConf` with values that match entries on the configuration page: [Configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)

Your cluster will need a copy of the code you are going to submit to it in its classpath. There are multiple ways to do this, you can manage it on the cluster manually or pass it in to the `SparkConf` with the `setJars` method.

As of Spark 1.3.1, you can only have 1 `SparkContext` created at a time per JVM. So if you want to submit concurrent applications from the same JVM you will need to manage this shared resource properly.

Answer (score -1):

> Check your spark-cluster from URl spark-master-hostname: if it is running fine 
>   go to the machine from where you want to launch the job 
>   (>> this machine should also has installed spark library to submit the job And) 
>   hit this command from you machine 
>   spark-submit --class  --jars  --master spark://:7077 .jar